# Windows update and SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 1

Tags: windows-update, sql-server-2008

My o/s (vista ultimate 64) has been offering this up since it was published on 6/14. Three times I downloaded and installed it, along with the attendant restart!

Info from the SQL Server Mgt Studio is below - why isn't windows update getting this one right, and how do I help it along?

Cheers,
Berryl

- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                       10.0.2531.0
- Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                      6.0.6002.18005
- Microsoft MSXML                      3.0 5.0 6.0
- Microsoft Internet Explorer                      9.0.8112.16421
- Microsoft .NET Framework                     2.0.50727.4214
- Operating System                     6.0.6002

Answer (score 1):

Successful updates will show up under Programs and Features.  There is also a log file in your windows directory that shows up if it failed. If it is there under Programs and Features AND on update, then you should run the Update fixer.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Open-the-Windows-Update-troubleshooter

If it DID fail, you should look at the log file or download the standalone version.  Just google *Update Name* Standalone.  A link to the Microsoft download center should be in the results.

Comment: i think its more of a sql server issue than an updater issue

Comment: The "stand alone" has a fairly complex installer has several pre-requisite tasks, all of which have a status of Passed except for the "Restart Required" (of course the computer has been restarted tho). Cheers